# Add dynamic url with external page in Wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting, users, page-template

I'm working on WordPress website, where user can publish his profile using URL. I've number of user who haven't matter with WordPress database.

Now website is like:

```
http://www.abc.com/
```

Now I've number of user who can access their profile:

So url becomes like:

```
http://www.abc.com/user1
```

I'm thinking to do like get detail of **'user1'** There is no page exist of 'user1' in wordpress page/post. It is store in external table in same database.

Anyone can suggest me how to I develop same kind of functionality in Wordpress.

Comment: it will be much more simple if you give them a unique prefix, like `abc.com/users/user1/`, then you can create the page `users` and add a rewrite rule and query var to pass the requested user to your page.

Comment: @Milo can you suggest me about rewrite rule? Is any documentation available? And Is it working with 'Post name' permalink?